# Nested select top 1 in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

having some problems figuring this one out.

select *,(select top 1 chicken_nr from chicken_photo where chicken = code order by [sort]) as Photo from Chicken

Code is a column in Table Chicken

Basically getting the cover photo for this chicken.

To make it clearer, I want it to return multiple rows from table Chicken. But only a single entry from chicken_photo.

```
var q = from chicken in data.chickens
                    join photos in data.chicken_photos
                    on chicken.Code equals photos.chicken                    
                    where chicken.Lang==lang && chicken.photographer_nr == nr
                    group chicken by new     {chicken.photographer,photos.Photograph_Nr,chicken.Title,chicken.Code}
```

Comment: actually it's for chicken farmers to do crossbreeding from, so I guess, yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can indeed be done such that it results in only one SQL query underneath.

If you perform the subselect as you have written against Entity Framework, then the Linq query will become a single SQL query.

```
    var q = from chicken in data.chickens
            where chicken.photographer_nr == nr && chicken.Lang == lang
            select new
            {
                chicken.photographer,
                chicken.Code,
                chicken.Title,
                Photo = (from cp in data.chicken_photos
                         where cp.chicken == chicken.Code
                         orderby cp.Sort
                         select cp.Photograph_Nr).FirstOrDefault()
            };
```

If your tables have proper primary and foreign key relationships, and proper navigation associations in Entity Framework then you can also achieve the same results this way:

```
    var q = from chicken in data.chickens
            where chicken.photographer_nr == nr && chicken.Lang == lang
            select new
            {
                chicken.photographer,
                chicken.Code,
                chicken.Title,
                Photo = c.chicken_photos.Select(cp => cp.Photograph_Nr).FirstOrDefault()
            };
```

And finally, to stay completely consistent and use only lambda-expressions:

```
    var q = data.chickens
       .Where(c => chicken.photographer_nr == nr && chicken.Lang == lang)
       .Select(c => new
            {
                c.photographer,
                c.Code,
                c.Title,
                Photo = c.chicken_photos.Select(cp => cp.Photograph_Nr).FirstOrDefault()
            }
        );
```

I prefer relying on entity navigation, as it forces the developer to create proper navigation associations in Entity Framework and proper foreign key relationships in the database.  This will almost always result in optimized SQL underneath.

It's not always up to the developer how the database is structured, so you may have to stick with the first approach and write the sub-select yourself.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.

Pretty obvious actually, too obvious :)

```
var q = from chicken in data.chickens
                where chicken.photographer_nr == nr && lang == chicken.Lang
                select new { chicken.photographer, chicken.Code, chicken.Title,Photo = (from b in data.chicken_photos where b.chicken==chicken.Code orderby b.Sort select b.Photograph_Nr).FirstOrDefault() };
```

Comment: Take(1) is redundant. First() will return the first value in the sequence, whether that sequence contains one or more values. Note that it will throw if there there are no photos, use FirstOrDefault() if you want to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer to reflect this better practice, although in my case photos is always populated

Comment: Not sure about if this is good coding though, if the query is returning 100 entries, that means 100 connections to the database for the select top 1

Stored procedures is probably the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var photo = (from c in chicken_photo where c.code = chicken orderby c.sort select c.chicken_nr).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
```

You should really flesh out your question more...

Comment: Hmm, I want multiple chickens, so I get multiple rows, but only retrieving one entry from chicken_photo